# raspberry pi 3 model B＋ で独立した4つのPWM出力を行いたい

Tags: raspberry-pi

こんにちは。
raspberry pi 3 model B で独立した4つのPWM出力を行いたい

raspberry pi3 model B+では、PWM出力を行えます。
ハードウェアPWM出力に対応pinは、4つあります。
しかし、独立に制御できるのは2組ずつしかありません。

```
PWM0(GPIO12,GPIO18)
PWM1(GPIO13,GPIO19)
```

独立した4つのpinをPWM出力するためには、どうすればよいのでしょうか。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raspberry Pi 3 だと32個のpinが使えるという記事がありました。
[Raspberry Pi 3 pigpioを使ってLチカ PWM編](https://hakengineer.xyz/2017/09/26/post-364/)

---

古い機種だと2系統までのようです。
[Raspberry PiでのハードウェアPWM](https://qiita.com/s417-lama/items/0ef64a7af3fcf6a56cc5#raspberry-pi%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AE%E3%83%8F%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%82%A6%E3%82%A7%E3%82%A2pwm)

> このあたりを見ると書いてあるんですが、ラズパイではハードウェアPWMに対応しているピンが4つあり、独立に制御できるのは2組ずつです。
>   古い記述だとラズパイのハードウェアPWMはGPIO18だけ、と書いてあったりするのですが、それはラズパイA、Bの話で、それ以降のモデルでは独立に2つのPWMを出力することができます。
>
> PWM Channel 0 : GPIO12、GPIO18  
>   PWM Channel 1 : GPIO13、GPIO19
>
> Channelが同一のピンはPWMを独立に制御できないので、Channel 0を共有しているGPIO12,18は別々のハードウェアPWMを出力できません。
>   逆に言えば、Channelを共有していれば同一のPWMを出力することができます。